# How to get the names of the files stored in NSDocumentsDirectory?

Tags: iphone, ios, filenames, nsdocumentdirectory

I have some files saved in my NSDocumentsDirectory, how do i get the names of those files and then display those names in a uitableview?

I just want to retrieve the name of the objects as NSString, I am able to retrieve the files as objects but not their names.

Here is the code for it:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSError * error;
objectsAtPathArray =  (NSMutableArray*)[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                      contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
[objectsAtPathArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Last line is to remove the .DS_Store file

Comment: adding a (for in) loop did the trick,

    for (NSString *fileName in self.objectsAtPathArray) {
    cell.textLabel.text = fileName;  
    }

Comment: So copy your comment above, past it into Your Answer, and submit it. When you can click the checkbox to accept it, this will prevent people like me reviewing what appears to be an unanswered question, and does you good as you get rated on the number of questions you approve an answer for!

Comment: I tried doing it. But i could not answer my own question before 8 hours. since I dont have enough reputation. And i did not delete the question since I thot it might prove useful for some1 else trying to find the solution for the same.

Comment: Fine - I didn't suggest you delete it - its good to have an answered question, and I guarantee that others will read it in the future since its answered! Nicely done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding a (for in) loop did the trick for me,

```
for (NSString *fileName in self.objectsAtPathArray){

   cell.textLabel.text = fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    objectsAtPathArray = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil]mutableCopy];

    for(int i = 0; i < [objectsAtPathArray count]; i++)
    {
       if (![[objectsAtPathArray objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:@".DS_Store"])
       {
         [NewArray addObject:[objectsAtPathArray objectAtIndex:i]];
          NSLog(@"NewArray=%@",[NewArray objectAtIndex:i]);
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work correct:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *imageFilenames = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [imageFilenames count]; i++)
    {

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,[imageFilenames objectAtIndex:i] ];

        if (![[imageFilenames objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:@".DS_Store"])
        {
          UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
          UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_myimage];
        }
    }
```